# What should we do with the "narrative vs descriptive" question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[What are the differences between narrative and descriptive writing?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3759/what-are-the-differences-between-narrative-and-descriptive-writing) has attracted a lot of low-quality answers, mostly one-liners.  What should we do with this question and its answers?  I'm tempted to close it as too broad or unclear, but I'd like to see some community input.  For now I've protected it.